# Which mobile game is in this OnePlus 5 review?

Tags: game-identification, mobile

Can you recognise this mobile game?

[image]

It's from a YouTube review video about OnePlus 5:

[image] [OnePlus 5 Review: Still the best value? - YouTube](https://youtu.be/OwJtExvtM3A?t=1m37s)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The game is [Clash Royale](http://supercell.com/en/games/clashroyale/) by Supercell.

It is available for both [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.supercell.clashroyale) and [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/clash-royale/id1053012308?mt=8).

[image: Official Screenshot from Google Play]

Comment: I wonder if this answer will get over 100 upvotes like the last one.

Comment: @BlueBarren it's unlikely, but hopefully it will. Gotta get that sweet internet points.

Comment: @BlueBarren Only if people upvote questions that show zero research effort.